# *ngIf não funciona como esperado, Angular

Tags: angular

Basicamente tenho seguinte `*ngIf`

```
<label>{{view._source.favoriteView }}</label>

       <!--Não é favorito-->
      <div *ngIf="view._source.favoriteView">
        <button (click)="unsetAsFavorite(view._id)" matTooltip="Favoritar" mat-icon-button >
          <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>

       <!--É favorito-->
      <div *ngIf="!view._source.favoriteView">
        <button (click)="setAsFavorite(view._id)" matTooltip="Desfavoritar" mat-icon-button color="warn" >
          <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
```

O `label` exibe o valor correto esperado (true / false), porém SEMPRE está entrando no primeiro `*ngIf`, mesmo sendo false, testei usar o `*ngIf` de todas formas disponíveis na documentação e nenhuma funcionou, o que estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que utilizar desta forma:

```
<div *ngIf="view._source.favoriteView === 'false'">
            <button (click)="setAsFavorite(view._id)" matTooltip="Favoritar" mat-icon-button >
              <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>

           <!--É favorito-->
          <div *ngIf="view._source.favoriteView === 'true'">
            <button (click)="unsetAsFavorite(view._id)" matTooltip="Desfavoritar" mat-icon-button color="warn" >
              <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
```

Pois os valores retornados eram do tipo 'String' e não Boolean